# Encoded special characters in parameters causing spring boot contract testing query does not match problem

Tags: encoding, spring-boot-test

While writing the spring boot contract testing on consumer side, I having problem when request parameters contains special characters. They'll automatically encoding causing the test failed due to the spring consider that the "Query does not match"

**"自动制动" has been encoded as "%E8%87%AA%E5%8A%A8%E5%88%B6%E5%8A%A8"**

Check the log, i could see: 
***Query: word = 自动制动 | word: %E8%87%AA%E5%8A%A8%E5%88%B6%E5%8A%A8          <<<<< Query does not match***

Here's my groovy file on producer side:
    Contract.make {
    description "Returns \"Auto hold\"'s canonical value_Mandarin"
    name "getSynonym_AutoHold_canonical_Mandarin"
    request {

```
    urlPath( "/synonyms"){
        headers {"accept: application/json;charset=UTF-8"}
        queryParameters {
            parameter("filter","canonical")
            parameter("lang", "cmn-CHN")
            parameter("word","自动制动")
        }

    }


    method GET()
}
response {
    status OK()
    headers {
        contentType applicationJson()
    }
    body '''
        {
                "canonical": "autohold",
                "word": "自动制动"
            }'''


}
```

}

And here's what I have in consumer side:

```
@Test
public void testSynonyms_Cmn(){
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    String url = "http://localhost:8080/synonyms";
    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);
    UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(url)
            .queryParam("filter","canonical")
            .queryParam("lang","cmn-CHN")
            .queryParam("word","自动制动");

    HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<>(httpHeaders);
    CentralizedSynonyms centralizedSynonyms = restTemplate.exchange(builder.toUriString(),  HttpMethod.GET, entity
            , CentralizedSynonyms.class).getBody();

    assertThat(centralizedSynonyms.getWord()).isEqualTo("自动制动");
    assertThat(centralizedSynonyms.getCanonical()).isEqualTo("autohold");
}
```

Comment: same issue here, have u found any resolution?

Answer (score 1):

I had something similar and fixed it with this:

```
    url value(consumer("/path1/path2/something%3Dsomethingelse"), producer("/path1/path2/something=somethingelse"))
```